# JavaFX Importing Images & Graphics

Tags: java, javafx

I am very new to Java and I'm working with the program Netbeans. I am very very confused on how to import images or even use the graphics to draw an image. I have set my scene and want to for example, import multiple images across the screen but I am stuck at the first step of getting an image onto the scene. Any suggestions on how to get the graphics to work would be a great start.

```
package spaceinvaders;

import java.util.Scanner;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author Twissted
 */

public class SpaceInvaders extends Application {

@Override
public void start ( Stage stage ) throws Exception {

    Pane root = new Pane ();
    Scene scene = new Scene ( root, 500, 500, Color.BLACK );
    stage.setTitle ( "Space Invaders" );
    stage.setScene ( scene );




    System.out.println ( "Please enter how many rows of aliens you wish to encounter: " );
    int r1;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner ( System.in );
    r1 = keyboard.nextInt ();


    stage.show ();

}



public static void main (String [] args ) {
    launch ( args );
}

}
```

I understand this is probably incredibly simple, I am good with the programming part but I just for the life of me can't figure out even after searching the internet how to get the graphics portion of this program working.

Comment: *Don't use `Scanner`* on your JavaFX application thread! You'll block it from running. Is your question about loading and displaying an PNG/JPEG image? Also, you might be able to spend more time by using a framework taking lots of the chores out of your hands, e.g. [FXGL](https://github.com/AlmasB/FXGL)

Comment: Honestly, I don't know any better. This is the only way I was able to figure out how to receive an input and assign it to a variable that I plan on using later to assign x and y positions to the images I wish to place on the scene. Imagine space invaders. I want to take user inputs for rows and columns and place a bunch of aliens on the screen. My main question is how do I display this PNG/JPEG image on the screen. It doesn't even have to be a PNG/JPEG even just a small square wherever I want and I can do the rest

Comment: It seems you need to first do research on `Event-Driven` programming. Then do some basic tutorial. You are getting ahead of yourself.

Comment: I agree with @Sedrick. Reading [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/index.html) might be a good place to start.

Comment: It's my first assignment after a week of learning in school. I've read the textbook up till this point and have gotten nothing from it nor my instructor. Gotta teach myself at this point. I have experience with Python but moving to Java it's quite different. I'll look into Event-Driven programming. I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create an `ImageView` and add it to your `Pane`. Move its `LayoutX` and `LayoutY` properties to position it on the screen. Inthe example the file `sprite.png` must be in the same package space as the class is. Make sure you package it the correct way.

```
ObservableList<Node> children = pane.getChildren();
ImageView sprite = new ImageView(getClass().getResource("sprite.png").toString());
 children.add(sprite);
 sprite.setLayoutX(300d);
 sprite.setLayoutY(20d);
```

I still advise you to use [FXGL](https://github.com/AlmasB/FXGL) though.

Comment: We are learning using Netbeans 8.2 it looks to me like FXGL is another program? I wish ...

Comment: NetBeans is an IDE, FXGL is a library that helps you to create a game in JavaFX by providing you with common behavior.  Any decent programmer will use a library instead of wasting time by rolling out his own stuff.

Comment: Okay, I'll download it and do some research into if it could help me out down the road :)

Comment: Be sure to check out its wiki, explaining how to use it.